# How to have nested select dropdown that will fetch differently for the main list and the dependent list for htmx?

Tags: htmx

Was [requested](https://github.com/bigskysoftware/htmx/issues/320#issuecomment-757500818) by maintainer to repost here

### Issue

In https://htmx.org/examples/value-select/

I can tell that the `make` is directly in the html and when it changes, the hx-get is called to fetch a new list of models.

What if I want to have both the `make` and the `model` all rely on ajax?

meaning to say

```
            <select name="makes" id="makes" hx-get="/makes" hx-trigger="load">
                <option value="none">original</option>
            </select>
            <select name="models" id="models">
                <option value="none">original</option>
            </select>
```

i like to be able to fetch from `/makes` on load to get the list of makes option

and then somehow I can also fill up the dependent models as well.

I don't mind doing it as two requests. The reason is that in my situation the `makes` are also dependent on a 3rd party API

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I hope I understand what you want, but something like this should work:

```html
     <select name="makes" id="makes" hx-get="/makes" hx-trigger="load">
       <option value="none">original</option>
    </select>
    <select name="models" id="models"
            hx-get="/models" 
            hx-trigger="changed from:#makes"
            hx-include="#makes">
      <option value="none">original</option>
    </select>
```

So you add a trigger to the second drop down that listens for `changed` events on the `#makes` drop down and then fires up a request to the `/models` URL, including the value of the `#makes` drop down so you know what models to return.

Does that seem like what you want?

Comment: Is it possible to dynamically generate hx-get url based on the selected item from the dropdown list? something like hx-get="/baseufl/${selected value on change}". So it's expected to do the get call everytime a new value is selected?